# Getting std::bad_alloc in Arrow Dataset C++

Tags: c++, dataset, parquet, apache-arrow

I have to read subset of a huge parquet file (10GB) in C++, and I learn that I can filter/scan the parquet file using Arrow Dataset. At the moment I am simply just trying to re-create the example on the apache arrow website (see Arrow C++ Tabular Datasets section).

I kept running into the std::bad_alloc error when I tried to make the factory

```
std::shared_ptr<FileSystem> fs;
std::shared_ptr<ParquetFileFormat> format;
fs::FileSelector s;

s.base_dir = "C:/parquet_data";

ds::FileSystemDatasetFactory::Make(fs, s, format,ds::FileSystemFactoryOptions());
```

So when the code gets to the "Make" part, I keep getting std::bad_alloc! Anyone know how I can fix this? I noticed that format->reader_options.dict_columns is huge after the initialisation, could this be the issue why I have std::bad_alloc error? How can I fix that?

Or is there another way I can filter a huge parquet file without using Arrow Dataset?
Many thanks

I am not sure what to try here.

Comment: Could you please include a minimal reproducible code snippet so we know exactly what code you're running? How many row groups does your Parquet file have here? If it's one, try splitting your file into many and see if the problem persists.

Comment: How much ram does your machine have?  It could be it is trying to load the entire 10GB file into memory.

Comment: I am currently using this example from Github, https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/main/cpp/examples/arrow/dataset_parquet_scan_example.cc

So when I get to line 88, then I get the std::bad_alloc error.

Hmmmmmm, I think at some point, we might even want to do more than just 10GB, so it's better not to load the entire file for us

Comment: Hmm, I agree that we probably need to see more of your code (the example works and so it would seem that you might be doing something different).  It seems strange to me that the `ds::FileSystemDatasetFactory::Make` call would lead to running out of memory.  This call will, at most, list all of the files in the dierctory `C:/parquet_data` and maybe also read the parquet metadata.  How many parquet files do you have?  How large is the metadata in each file?

Comment: [std::bad_alloc can be thrown on a bad value](https://godbolt.org/z/4xnrWMPqY), and not have anything to do with how much memory you have.